# Is type=button necessary with aria-label?

Tags: html, wai-aria

I read that the implicit value for a button type is `submit`. To make UI buttons, I also read that we need therefore to specify the `type=button` attribute.

For instance:

```html
<button type="button">Click me</button>
```

However, I've seen this example as an accessible button:

```html
<button aria-label="undo">&#xE000;</button>
```

I notice that it doesn't have the `type=button` attribute.

If `aria-label` is defined on a button, does it implicitly mean that the button is of `type=button`?

If not, is the above example (undo button) incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type` and `aria-label` are unrelated.

If you don't specify a `type` on a `<button>`, then the default type is `submit`.  If your button is contained in a `<form>`, then the onclick() for the button will run and the form will be submitted.

If your type is `button`, then the form will not be submitted.  Only the onclick() for the button will run.

See the [`<button>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/sec-forms.html#the-button-element) spec.

The reason the second example has [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-label) is because there is no visible text on the button.  An icon font is used (like an image) and in order for a screen reader to know what to announce for the button, `aria-label` is specified.

Comment: so the right way to write the button is then: <button aria-label="undo" type="button">&#xE000;</button> ?

Comment: if your button is contained in a <form>, then you need `type="button"` if you **don't** want the button to automatically submit the form.  if your button is just a stand alone element on your page (not in a <form>), then you don't need `type="button"`.  either way, you **do** need the `aria-label="undo"`